# while passing a date from jsp page to servlet instead of passing a proposed date sysdate is passing

Tags: java, jsp, date, servlets

I used a datepicker to pick the date format.
now while passing this date from a jsp page to servlet page instead of passing the date which i putted a sysdate is passing.

---

---

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String getdate = request.getParameter("selectDate");
    String [] date = getdate.split("-");

    int date1 = Integer.parseInt(date[0].trim());
    int month = Integer.parseInt(date[1].trim());
    int year = Integer.parseInt(date[2].trim());
    java.sql.Date sD=new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println(sD);
```

these are some sysouts

```
In Book Support
In Database Connection
Driver is still loading...
Driver Loaded.....
Connection established.....
2013-10-28
 support_id=0, booking_date=2013-10-28, descriprtion=asdasd, address=sadas, contact_number=234]
In Add Support
 support_id=0, booking_date=2013-10-28, descriprtion=asdasd, address=sadas, contact_number=234]
1record added
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
java.sql.Date sD=new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println(sD);
```

You created new calendar instance and so the result

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse received `String` to `Date` and use it to create further `Date` instances (if required)

Comment: _Use SimpleDateFormat ti parse received String to Date and use it to create further Date instances (if required)_